# How should I store data(100 x 2 array) in Gatsby?

Tags: graphql, content-management-system, gatsby, graphql-js

I'm developing a map which loads 100 location pinpoints. To do so, I want to save double array of 100 rows and 2 column, which saves 100 locations.(latitude/longitude)

I am considering CMS or GraphQL-filesystem, but I don't know which to use. I want to to prioritize webpage load time, but if possible, it'd be nice to conceal my data.

Where should I store my data? Please give me advise. Other options are also welcome Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 locations with latitude and longitude is still only a few KB of data. You do not need sophisticated data storage solutions for this.

The easiest way is to use your [local filesystem](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/sourcing-from-the-filesystem/) i.e. an array and store it in a javascript file inside your project.

The next easiest way is to use any external solution that Gatsby allows. Take a look at their possible [external sources](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/content-and-data/).

Comment: I just added data.js and created var array = new int[100][2]; Not sure if it's meant to be that way in web development.

Comment: Web development uses many same paradigms as other areas of development: Start with the easiest fastest solution for the requirements. If the requirements change only then you need to think about more sophisticated ways: An array file is totally okay to use as your data storage solution!